# Scratch your mind, who am I?

Tags: riddle, computer-puzzle

Scratch your mind,

You will get stuck if you forgot me :(
Try to make a cute wink by combining curve with me
I can destroy your whole day if you missed me, and you finally found devil
OMG!! Is the usual reaction after you put me.
People are using me every day, although they might seen me in 1984 in widescreen.

Guess, Who am I?

Hint 1 :

> I'm also known as one of the film name.

Hint 2 :

> My other name is film name which was released in 1984

Comment: Please check tag wikis before using them.

Comment: is this tech-related??

Comment: Yes it's related to software technology

Comment: 1984 reminds me of apple... but I can't make it work ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possibly

> a semicolon

You will get stuck if you forgot me :(

> In coding, forgetting a semicolon at the end of a line can cause errors.

Try to make a cute wink by combining curve with me

> Use it with a parenthesis to make ;)

I can destroy your whole day if you missed me, and you finally found devil

> As @sid said, possibly people search for errors after writing a code and then at last notice that they missed a semicolon

OMG!! Is the usual reaction after you put me.

> Could be referencing the use of ;) in a text

People are using me every day, although they might seen me in 1984 in widescreen.

> Not sure yet

Comment: That last spoiler is blatantly factually incorrect. I agree this sounds like the answers, but I just can't see how it works with some of the more obscure clues.

Comment: Also the third line is not yet explained... Maybe, it means that people search for errors after writing a code and then at last notice that they missed a semicolon..

Comment: I searched google and found that he "deliberately sidestepped semicolons throughout that book".  I should have checked further.  I still believe this most likely the answer.

Comment: @Sid I was thinking along those same lines.  That's a possiblity

Comment: I found at least 10 semicolons in one chapter, so I wouldn't trust that source. Or maybe you misinterpreted it. Anyway, I'm not clear that line is referencing the book 1984 anyway, especially since it mentions "widescreen."

Comment: @C.Woods I looked up "1984 widescreen" and the movie "1984" showed up, seems a bit obscure, but could possibly be a link.

Comment: Semicolon is the right answer but you did not solve last clue..@rlord3534
I have added hint check it out.

Comment: Solution of Last clue of widescreen : It is related to movie as mention in Hint, and it name is "terminator" . Usually  semicolon known as terminator also. BTW thanks guys for your best try..